Prove that the Fourier coefficients of the Dolph-Chebyshev window are positive
Suppose parameter $x_0 >1$, integer $M \geq 1$. Let $T_n(x)$ denote Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind, with recursive relation: $T_0(x)=1, T_1(x)=x, T_{n+1}(x) = 2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$. The Dolph-Chebyshev window is defined by
$$
W(\theta) := \frac{T_{2M}(x_0\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}))}{T_{2M}(x_0)}.
$$
It has a finite Fourier series
$$
W(\theta) = \sum_{n=-M}^{M} w_n \exp(in\theta),
$$
where the coefficients are given by the discrete Fourier transform as follows:
$$
w_n = \frac{1}{2M+1} \sum_{m=-M}^{M} W\left(\frac{2\pi m}{2M+1}\right) \cdot \exp(\frac{ -2\pi i mn}{2M+1}).
$$
Prove that $w_n >0$ for all $n \in \{0,1,\dots,M\}$.

This site does not help with homework problems unless an attempt is made. Give the problem a try and then the forum can help on where you're having issues.

Using the fact that $W(\theta)$ is real and even, we can prove that $w_n=w_{-n}$ are real numbers. The question is how to prove that they are all positive, which is needed since Eq.(152) requires them to be positive.
